# Anylogic : Release block with no set_resourcesGoHome() function available

Tags: anylogic

I have one Release block (out of a number similar blocks) that is not providing the set_resourcesGoHome() function.    [functions list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dk513.png)

This is just a standard release block based on a seize block, in the same way as others I've created that have the function listed:

[release block](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CPuJZ.png)

The block has the gui option:

[Moving resources option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1VS2R.png)

I have tried replacing it

Comment: that function doesn't exist.. where did you get it from?